# salesforce SOQL can't get datetime in local time

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql

My objective is to count Lead records based on simple date range query in local time

```
Integer TotalLeads = [ Select Count() From Lead where createddate >= fromdate  CreatedDate <= todate];
```

Fairly basic.  However, the issue I'm running into is I only want to count the leads for the "local" time not UTC; createddate is in UTC for lead records.

Sample dates:
From: 03/23/2017
To: 03/29/2017

For these sample dates and my local time is UTC - 7 (Los Angeles), so my query would be

```
Integer TotalLeads = [ Select Count() From Lead where createddate >= 2017-03-23T07:00:00z AND  CreatedDate <= 2017-03-30T06:59:59z];
```

If these are my dates, how do I append the local time so from date is 2017-03-23T07:00:00z and to date is 2017-03-30T06:59:59z?

Using from date first, I was able to do the following but can't figure how to keep it in local time

```
        // Date 
        date ds = date.valueof('2017-03-23');
        string dm = string.valueOf( ds.month());
        string dd = string.valueOf(ds.day());
        string dy = string.valueOf(ds.year());

        // DateTime Midnight (UTC)
        String SDate = string.valueof(dm +'/' + dd + '/' + dy + ' 12:00 AM');
        system.debug(SDate); // -> 3/23/2017 12:00 AM

        // DateTime (Local Time)
        datetime ds2 = datetime.parse(SDate );
        system.debug(ds2); // -> 2017-03-23 07:00:00

        system.debug(ds2.format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'hh:mm:ss'')); // -> 2017-03-23T12:00:00
```

As you can see, using ds2.format put its in the format I need but back to UTC (midnight), I need it to be 2017-03-23T07:00:00

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Figured what I was doing wrong.  The date calculation was fine, it had to do with how this was being passed to a batch job.

Answer (score 0):

Figured what I was doing wrong. The date calculation was fine, it had to do with how this was being passed to a batch job.